# Using List/Histogram Data As A Weighted Function?

Tags: list-manipulation, fitting, distributions

I have a list of data points that I would like to use as a weighted function. The data represents the number of particles within a bin of a particle distribution.

Ultimately I would like to multiply the distribution with a continuous function (i.e. x^3) and then `NIntegrate` the whole thing. So, I am a little confused on how to go about doing this with this data set. Do I:

1. Fit the data to some continuous function?
2. Leave the data in binned form and somehow multiply the binned data (particle distribution) against my function?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The data is listed below:

```
z = {-5.347621813908679*10^-002, -4.916164579677237*10^-002, 
     -4.484707345445796*10^-002, -4.053250111214354*10^-002, 
     -3.621792876982912*10^-002, -3.190335642751470*10^-002, 
     -2.758878408520029*10^-002, -2.327421174288587*10^-002, 
     -1.895963940057145*10^-002, -1.464506705825704*10^-002, 
     -1.033049471594261*10^-002, -6.015922373628198*10^-003, 
     -1.701350031313782*10^-003, 2.613222311000633*10^-003, 
     6.927794653315056*10^-003, 1.124236699562947*10^-002, 
     1.555693933794389*10^-002, 1.987151168025830*10^-002, 
     2.418608402257272*10^-002, 2.850065636488713*10^-002, 
     3.281522870720156*10^-002, 3.712980104951598*10^-002, 
     4.144437339183039*10^-002, 4.575894573414481*10^-002, 
     5.007351807645923*10^-002, 5.438809041877364*10^-002, 
     5.870266276108806*10^-002, 6.301723510340247*10^-002, 
     6.733180744571690*10^-002, 7.164637978803132*10^-002, 
     7.596095213034573*10^-002, 8.027552447266015*10^-002, 
     8.459009681497456*10^-002, 8.890466915728898*10^-002, 
     9.321924149960340*10^-002, 9.753381384191781*10^-002, 
     1.018483861842322*10^-001, 1.061629585265466*10^-001, 
     1.104775308688611*10^-001, 1.147921032111755*10^-001, 
     1.191066755534899*10^-001, 1.234212478958043*10^-001, 
     1.277358202381188*10^-001, 1.320503925804332*10^-001, 
     1.363649649227476*10^-001, 1.406795372650620*10^-001, 
     1.449941096073764*10^-001, 1.493086819496908*10^-001, 
     1.536232542920052*10^-001, 1.579378266343197*10^-001, 
     1.622523989766341*10^-001, 1.665669713189485*10^-001, 
     1.708815436612629*10^-001, 1.751961160035773*10^-001, 
     1.795106883458917*10^-001, 1.838252606882062*10^-001, 
     1.881398330305206*10^-001, 1.924544053728350*10^-001, 
     1.967689777151494*10^-001, 2.010835500574638*10^-001, 
     2.053981223997782*10^-001, 2.097126947420926*10^-001, 
     2.140272670844071*10^-001, 2.183418394267215*10^-001, 
     2.226564117690359*10^-001, 2.269709841113504*10^-001, 
     2.312855564536648*10^-001, 2.356001287959792*10^-001, 
     2.399147011382936*10^-001, 2.442292734806080*10^-001, 
     2.485438458229224*10^-001, 2.528584181652369*10^-001, 
     2.571729905075513*10^-001, 2.614875628498657*10^-001, 
     2.658021351921801*10^-001, 2.701167075344945*10^-001, 
     2.744312798768089*10^-001, 2.787458522191234*10^-001, 
     2.830604245614378*10^-001, 2.873749969037522*10^-001, 
     2.916895692460666*10^-001, 2.960041415883810*10^-001, 
     3.003187139306954*10^-001, 3.046332862730098*10^-001, 
     3.089478586153243*10^-001, 3.132624309576387*10^-001, 
     3.175770032999531*10^-001, 3.218915756422675*10^-001, 
     3.262061479845819*10^-001, 3.305207203268963*10^-001, 
     3.348352926692108*10^-001, 3.391498650115252*10^-001, 
     3.434644373538396*10^-001, 3.477790096961540*10^-001, 
     3.520935820384684*10^-001, 3.564081543807828*10^-001, 
     3.607227267230973*10^-001, 3.650372990654117*10^-001, 
     3.693518714077261*10^-001, 3.736664437500405*10^-001};
frequency = {8.100000000000000*10^+001, 1.610000000000000*10^+003, 
             8.081000000000000*10^+003, 1.370800000000000*10^+004, 
             1.071500000000000*10^+004, 7.606000000000000*10^+003, 
             5.665000000000000*10^+003, 4.728000000000000*10^+003, 
             4.215000000000000*10^+003, 3.590000000000000*10^+003, 
             3.190000000000000*10^+003, 2.795000000000000*10^+003, 
             2.468000000000000*10^+003, 2.261000000000000*10^+003, 
             2.069000000000000*10^+003, 1.914000000000000*10^+003, 
             1.736000000000000*10^+003, 1.705000000000000*10^+003, 
             1.490000000000000*10^+003, 1.396000000000000*10^+003, 
             1.182000000000000*10^+003, 1.178000000000000*10^+003, 
             1.003000000000000*10^+003, 9.440000000000000*10^+002, 
             9.150000000000000*10^+002, 8.160000000000000*10^+002, 
             7.100000000000000*10^+002, 7.240000000000000*10^+002, 
             7.000000000000000*10^+002, 6.700000000000000*10^+002, 
             6.210000000000000*10^+002, 5.100000000000000*10^+002, 
             5.000000000000000*10^+002, 4.870000000000000*10^+002, 
             4.640000000000000*10^+002, 4.030000000000000*10^+002, 
             3.560000000000000*10^+002, 3.540000000000000*10^+002, 
             3.700000000000000*10^+002, 3.470000000000000*10^+002, 
             3.330000000000000*10^+002, 3.140000000000000*10^+002, 
             2.710000000000000*10^+002, 2.630000000000000*10^+002, 
             2.540000000000000*10^+002, 2.480000000000000*10^+002, 
             2.260000000000000*10^+002, 2.250000000000000*10^+002, 
             2.240000000000000*10^+002, 1.810000000000000*10^+002, 
             1.730000000000000*10^+002, 2.090000000000000*10^+002, 
             1.210000000000000*10^+002, 1.550000000000000*10^+002, 
             1.240000000000000*10^+002, 1.200000000000000*10^+002, 
             1.270000000000000*10^+002, 1.140000000000000*10^+002, 
             1.390000000000000*10^+002, 1.340000000000000*10^+002, 
             1.230000000000000*10^+002, 1.080000000000000*10^+002, 
             9.900000000000000*10^+001, 8.600000000000000*10^+001, 
             8.300000000000000*10^+001, 9.100000000000000*10^+001, 
             8.600000000000000*10^+001, 7.700000000000000*10^+001, 
             8.100000000000000*10^+001, 6.200000000000000*10^+001, 
             6.600000000000000*10^+001, 6.800000000000000*10^+001, 
             4.500000000000000*10^+001, 4.900000000000000*10^+001, 
             3.900000000000000*10^+001, 5.000000000000000*10^+001, 
             3.600000000000000*10^+001, 4.500000000000000*10^+001, 
             3.600000000000000*10^+001, 2.900000000000000*10^+001, 
             4.300000000000000*10^+001, 2.600000000000000*10^+001, 
             3.200000000000000*10^+001, 3.000000000000000*10^+001, 
             2.000000000000000*10^+001, 2.700000000000000*10^+001, 
             2.300000000000000*10^+001, 2.400000000000000*10^+001, 
             1.700000000000000*10^+001, 2.300000000000000*10^+001, 
             2.500000000000000*10^+001, 2.300000000000000*10^+001, 
             1.800000000000000*10^+001, 2.000000000000000*10^+001, 
             2.100000000000000*10^+001, 1.100000000000000*10^+001, 
             9.000000000000000*10^+000, 7.000000000000000*10^+000, 
             5.000000000000000*10^+000, 5.000000000000000*10^+000};
 data = Transpose@{z, frequency};
 ListPlot[data, Axes -> True, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Have a look at `Interpolation`.

Answer (score 2):

**1. "Multiply the distribution with a continuous function (i.e. x^3)"**
I'll call the new data `data2`

```
data2 = Transpose@{z, frequency*z^3}

ListPlot[data2, Axes -> True, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: data2]

**2. "`NIntegrate` the whole thing"**
An [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) for `data2` can be found with

```
data2IP = Interpolation[data2]
```

and numerically integrated with

```
NIntegrate[data2IP[x], {x, 0, Max@z}]
```

$\ $`0.227143`

The final result depends on the chosen `InterpolationOrder` (with the default being 3):

```
NIntegrate[
   Interpolation[data2, InterpolationOrder -> #][x], {x, 0, Max@z}] & /@ Range[0, 5]
```

$\ $`{0.227745, 0.227182, 0.227303, 0.227143, 0.227002, 0.227153}`